# Where can I find quests for my level in Final Fantasy 14?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

While I'm hoping answers will be generic enough to apply to a wide audience, here is my specific situation:

I played the free trial that is offered for FF14 and was happily leveling up Conjurer until I hit level 20. Since classes are capped at 20 during the free trial, I had to switch classes and find a different area to level in since I was essentially level 1. Sometime after the free trial expired, I purchased the full version of the game up to Heavensward.

Since coming back and having no real indication of where I should go to continue leveling my Conjurer, I looked up a few guides which indicated heading to South Shroud. But the information I've been finding mostly pertains to power-leveling, which I'm not too concerned about. Other than a handful of random quests, the only things I've been able to do are Levequests and Fates, along with the occasional Guildhest. While the class quests are very interesting, they're pretty short while Levequests and Fates are starting to become a little boring. I'm currently a level 25 Conjurer.

My question: Where should I go in order to complete new quests? If answers are looking to be specific to my situation, then assume a level range of 25-35. Ideally, a detailed breakdown of the various quest hubs and level ranges would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Ctrl-U` will open the Recommendations window. This handy helper will list all the quests in the current zone that are around your level and available.

Second, as to your specific question... Around level 25, in the Black Shroud the area you want is probably Quarrymill down in South Shroud, heading eastward towards Buscarron's Druthers and from there south toward Camp Tranquil as you level up further, continuing on to Eastern Thanalan in the south or Central Shroud in the north, where you'll find 25-30 and 30-35 enemies and quests.

Third, I take it you've completed your level 25 class quest? If not, do so; it'll likely send you into the area you're just about ready for.

I don't know which point of the Main Scenario you are at (You can tell those by the frilly bits around the exclamation mark icon) but once you've been to all the remembrance festivals you should probably head over to Vesper Bay and meet your new best friends for the next thirty or so levels. Going through the MSQ will also unlock various new dungeons and trials as you encounter them, which will vastly increase your range of options.

All that said, the game *does* expect you to make up the occasional level shortfall by running FATEs, dungeons, guildhests, levequests, roulettes, challenges and whatnot. Probably the main reason they added so many different ways to get XP to the game.

Speaking of challenges, I absolutely encourage you to unlock your [challenge log](http://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Challenge_Log) if you haven't already; you can get it via a [quest](http://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Rising_to_the_Challenge) in Limsa Lominsa and it's a big help in every category.

Class specific there are also your tiered hunt logs - a specific bunch of critters you're encouraged to test your critter-murdering skills against; completing each tier is worth a hefty chunk of bonus XP.

Do Roulettes whenever you feel like it; conjurers generally don't have to wait long for a queue, and the daily bonus is worth half a level easy.

Hope any of this helps.

Comment: All great advice, and will hopefully be useful for others. For my personal situation, I had inadvertently left the main scenario quests behind by simply following the trail of available quests from area to area (very much like if I were playing WoW) until I ended up in a spot where there were no quests available anywhere. Once I rediscovered the main scenario, I pretty much rode that, the class quests, and the various daily tasks available the rest of the way to level 50. So, I had to back-track a bit, but got straightened out.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've completed the main scenario up to level 20 the main scenario quests should continue in the Waking Sands near Horizon in Western Thanalan or in East Shroud around Hawthorn Hut or Little Solace. If you haven't progressed that far, check in Eastern Thanalan.

In the future if you get lost, you can usually check your journal, and go to the location that the last quest you completed was finished; the next quest is usually started from the same NPC, or an NPC near by.